# WebUSB interface example

Tags: javascript, chromium, webusb

I understand the security concerns and changes implemented like described here:
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/LZXocaeCwDw/GLfAffGLAAAJ

But since my devices do not work anymore I was wondering:

1. Is there a example interface descriptor which I can use to implement into my USB device (it would help if it would work without a udev rule or a Windows driver which must be installed by the user)?
2. Are there preferred classes to use which will be supported for a longer time (e.g. 0xFF vendor specific)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your existing interface descriptor, with `bInterfaceClass` set to 0xff for vendor specific rather than its current value will work just fine. On Linux a udev rule will be required to make the USB device node writable by the browser. On Windows you will need to implement the [Microsoft OS 2.0 descriptor platform capability descriptor](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/5/6/3563ED4A-F318-4B66-A181-AB1D8F6FD42D/MS_OS_2_0_desc.docx) in order to instruct Windows to load the right driver by default when the device is connected. An example of all of these descriptors is included in the WebUSB Arduino library in [WebUSB.cpp](https://github.com/webusb/arduino/blob/gh-pages/library/WebUSB/WebUSB.cpp).
2. Your interface should probably be vendor-specific (0xff) unless it is implementing a standardized device class that is not one of the protected interface classes.